# Labelling a hclust dendogram using multiple factors

Tags: r, label, hclust

I am doing some hierarchical cluster analyses of some ecological data & I am struggling w/the labels, which are numeric and all but meaningless:
[dendogram w/meaningless labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxPt.png)

Essentially I would like to bind together the two factorial columns in my data to create labels that clarify which data points are what, and I do not understand R's labelling system well enough to understand what I am trying to do.

If seeing my code will help you understand better, then here it is:

```
nta ##data frame: 32obs, 40 variables - 
    ##$Quadrant factor w/8levels
    ##$Position factor w/4levels
nta.bc ##bray-curtis dissimilarity matrix of data
nta.hclust ##average-linked cluster object of nta.bc

##attempt to plot w/labels
plot(nta.hclust) +
  labels(nta, which = c(nta$Quadrant,nta$Position)) +
  rect.hclust(nta.hclust,k=4)
```

does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What distance/similarity matrix you're using to build the hclust? If your matrix has the labels then your plots should also have them.

Comment: Bray-Curtis through the vegan package function vegdist

I could add the columns to the dist matrix but as I would like to aggregate the labels from the values of the two factors would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You should include sample data using `dput()` so that we can illustrate the answer with a sample of your own data. Also provide actual code not comments since the problem may lie in your code. Here is an example using the `varespec` data that is included in package `vegan`. The main problem is that you are using `ggplot2` syntax with base graphics functions. Did you get error messages that you did not include in your question?

```
data(varespec)    # Load varspec data set included in vegan
vsp.bc <- vegdist(varespec, method="bray")
vsp.hcl <- hclust(vsp.bc, method="average")
plot(vsp.hcl, labels=paste("Plot", rownames(varespec)))
rect.hclust(vsp.hcl, k=4)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

Comment: That's worked for me!


plot(nta.hclust, label=paste(nta$Quadrant,nta$Position)) +
  rect.hclust(nta.hclust,k=4)



this code does return an error:
non-numeric argument to binary operator
which I imagine comes from using the '+' to run both lines of code sequentially, however, I can't see how this would affect the results of my dendogram

Comment: It is your `labels( . . . )` line. There is a `labels()` function in R, but it returns labels from an object so it does not have a `which=` argument. The `labels=` argument in the `plot(..)` function sets the labels for the dendrogram.